# How do I read from a text file and create instances of classes with the lines of text to put them into an array?

Tags: ruby, class

I have a text file, named "test.txt", that reads exactly as follows:

```
Hello world
Cat and dog
It is hot outside
```

And in my code, I'm trying to read the line of text from the file and create an instance of the "Object" class with the sentence that I just read. I know how to do it without using instances of classes, but for the purpose of a larger project that I'm working on, I'm trying to understand how to read lines from a file, create an instance of a class with the read line, and then create an array of the class instances. Am I on the right track?

```
class Object
  attr_accessor :str

  def initialize(sent)
    @str = sent
  end
end

class Solution
  attr_accessor :array

  def initialize
    @array = Array.new
  end

  def make_Array
    File.open("test.txt").each do | line |
      @array << Object.new(line.chomp)
    end
    print @array
  end
end
```

I also kept seeing a warning message that mentioned Object being instantiated and an infinite loop, could someone explain to me what that means?

Comment: This will overwrite `Object::initialize`, the consequences of which will not be pretty.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Yes, I kept seeing that warning message. What would be the correct way to do it?

Comment: So why monkey patching `Object` instead of creating your own class?

Answer (score 0):

I'd highly recommend you to create your own class.

```
class LineWrapper
  attr_reader :content  # if you don't want others to change the value, make the attribute read-only.

  def initialize(content)
    @content = content
  end
end

# suppose the file size is small enough to hold in memory
array = File.readlines('test.txt').map!{|line| LineWrapper.new(line)}

# print the array
pp array
```

But before you go for this approach, you should ask yourself why you need the extra class? Are simple strings not good enough? "For the purpose of a large project" is not enough to convince me that I need to create wrapper classes because Ruby strings are soooooo good that they can almost do whatever I want. If that's not enough, I'd include `ActiveSupport` in my project.

Comment: Why is using map better here?? I guess I'm confused as to why it's ok to use map here, but putting the sentence directly into the array after reading it from the file gives me the warning message.

Comment: And one of the requirements in my assignment was to put the class instances into an array that was an instance variable in a different class. So would it still be ok to use map in that situation?

Comment: @Karen the warning comes from `Object.new`, not from `Array::<<`. If you override `Object#initialize` and put `Object.new(line)` in the block of `map`, it will still warn you.

Comment: @Karen you need a class whose instance holds an array that contains multiple `LineWrapper` instances. I believe you can figure that out by yourself :)